# Operand type clash error when executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a table called `account`:

[image: TableDefinition]

I also created a table type called `account_TT`:

```
CREATE TYPE account_TT AS TABLE
(
    AccountID nvarchar(50)
)
```

I then created a stored procedure to insert/update records in the account table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertorUpadte] 
@account_TT AS account_TT READONLY

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    MERGE dbo.[account] prj
    USING @account_TT tt
    ON prj.AccountID = tt.AccountID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET prj.CounterSeq = prj.CounterSeq+1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (AccountID,CounterSeq)
    VALUES (tt.AccountID, 1);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

To test this stored procedure I right clicked on it and selected `Execute Stored Procedure` and gave a value for the parameter `@account_TT`:

[image: ExecuteWithParameter]

It then throws an error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_InsertorUpadte, Line 2
>   Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with account_TT
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

Why is this error thrown and how can I resolve the issue causing the error?

Comment: Show the `exec` you used to call this procedure

Comment: @Prdp I just right clicked and tried to Execute it. As in the image it asked me the input parameter

Comment: Possible same problem as here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789560/sql-server-table-type-clash-operand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't execute a stored procedure that uses a table valued parameter using the GUI provided by SSMS. You need to write the your test manually:

```
DECLARE @account_TT AS account_TT
INSERT INTO @account_TT VALUES('IT')
EXEC usp_InsertorUpadte @account_TT
```

Comment: We I give the above in the new query window it says `Couldnot find the stored Procedure`

Comment: Make sure you are running on the correct database and schema.